# Jquery selecting a parents child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate, parent

I am trying to access the child OF the parent OF a specific div (the "content" div within the "container" div) to animate in Jquery. Currently i am using...

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".container").click(function(){
    $(this).find('.item').slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
</script>
```

...so that when you click on the container, the "content" div will toggle expanding and shrinking.
However, what i would really like is to click on the "click ME" div to expand the other div, so that when you click anywhere on the content, the content does not shrink again!

[image]

It would be VERY convenient to select the child of the parent div. I am presuming that the selector may be something along the lines of:

```
    $(this).parent.find('.item').slideToggle("slow");
```

But i really dont know!

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(this).closest('your parent').find('.item').slideToggle("slow");
```

`parent` is a method so `$(this).parent().find('.item')` makes more sense.

If `.item` is a sibling of `.container` then you can just do `$(this).siblings('.find').slideToggle("slow")`

- [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest)
- [.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings)

Comment: thanks alot, it works!! - and also that must have been one of the quickest responses i have ever encountered; GOOD JOB!