# Why does Jquery parent child selecter return undefined?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Why jquery parent child selector is not working here :

```js
$(document).on('change', 'select[name="slct_sec"]', function() {
  var cls_1 = $(this).closest('article').find('select[name="slct_cls"]').val();
  console.log(cls_1);

  var cls_1_bis = $(this).parent().siblings().find('select[name="slct_cls"]').val();
  console.log(cls_1_bis);
});


$("#productTableServerSide").on('change', '.server-dropdown', function(event) {
  //ancienne valeur
  var oldValue = $.data(this, 'itemValue');
  //nouvelle valeur
  var newValue = $(this).val();

  console.log('break1');
  //not working
  var itemName = $(this).closest('tbody').find('.col-name').val();
  console.log('itemName : ', itemName);

  //not working 
  var itemName1 = $(this).parent().children('.col-name').val();
  console.log('itemName1 : ', itemName1);

  //not working 
  var itemName2 = $(this).parent().siblings().find('select[name="values"]').val();
  console.log('itemName2 : ', itemName2);

  //not working 
  var itemName3 = $(this).parent().children('.col-name').find('select[name="values"]').val();
  console.log('itemName3 : ', itemName3);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Example from Internet which is working</p>
<article>
  <section>
    <select name='slct_cls'>
      <option value='1'>One</option>
      <option value='2'>Two</option>
    </select>
  </section>
  <br/>
  <section>
    <select name='slct_sec'>
      <option value='1'>A</option>
      <option value='2'>B</option>
    </select>
  </section>
</article>

<br/>

<p>My Example</p>
<table id="productTableServerSide" class="table table-bordered" style="width:100%;">
  <thead class="thead-dark text-white">
    <tr>
      <th>Check</th>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>The product name</th>
      <th>The product value</th>
      <th>Dropdown</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td class="col-checkbox sorting_1">
        <input id="check0" type="checkbox" class="server-checkbox">
      </td>
      <td class=" col-action">
        <a href="/Data/Product/0">Action</a>
      </td>
      <td class=" col-name">item 0</td>
      <td class=" col-value">3</td>
      <td class=" col-dropdown">
        <select id="drop3" class="server-dropdown custom-select custom-select-sm form-control form-control-sm" name="values">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3" selected="">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="2130554612">2130554612</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td class="col-checkbox sorting_1">
        <input id="check1" type="checkbox" class="server-checkbox">
      </td>
      <td class=" col-action">
        <a href="/Data/Product/1">Action</a>
      </td>
      <td class=" col-name">item 1</td>
      <td class=" col-value">1436184776</td>
      <td class=" col-dropdown">
        <select id="drop1436184776" class="server-dropdown custom-select custom-select-sm form-control form-control-sm" name="values">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="1436184776" selected="">1436184776</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I've used an example from here : [Jquery selecting a parents child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178510/jquery-selecting-a-parents-child) which didn't work for me.

The console.log returns `undefined` => which means that either the variable is undefined or something else

Could you help me?

Comment: What do you want to find with that code? Knowing that would help **a lot** in terms of helping us help you fix it.

Comment: The `HTML` section of the snippet editor is supposed to only contain the content of the `<body>` element and not the whole document (`<html>...</html>)`) -> [I've been told to create a “runnable” example with “Stack Snippets”, how do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: `$(this).parent().siblings().find()`. Judging from your markup `.siblings()` needs to be removed. Else you are searching the wrong element. Depends what you want to find tho.

Comment: `.col-name` is a `div`, so it has no `.val()` value

Comment: It looks like you need to understand how traversing the DOM works and what `find()`, `children()`, `parent()`, `siblings()` actually do. I suggest reading the jquery documentation.

Comment: You need to be sure you know what `this` is in all cases. When this=select.server-dropdown then `$(this).parent()` is the `td` that contains the `select` - so you probably want `$(this).parent().parent().siblings()` to get all the "tr"s - it can be easier to always use `.closest` instead of `.parent()`=direct parent - eg `$(this).closest("tr").siblings()`

Comment: Hi Crowder, it's meant to return 'item 0' = the value of the <td class=" col-name">

Comment: In which case `$(this).closest("tr").children('td.col-name').val();` or `$(this).parent().siblings(".col-name").val()`

Comment: I have tried all this things to show that it doesn't work, but my idea is this one :   var itemName = $(this).parent().children('.col-name').val();

Comment: this = select, so this.parent = td - so doesn't have any children with .col-name - there's many options, two I've provided above and another is: `$(this).parent().parent().children('.col-name').val();` (but I'm not a fan of `.parent().parent()` and prefer `.closest()` and it makes the HTML slightly less brittle

Comment: Hi Freedomn, I've tried this one : var itemName3 = $(this).parent().parent().children('.col-name').val();  but the console.log shows nothing!  Also I've tried this one :  var itemName3 = $(this).closest().children('.col-name').val(); and the console.log retruns undefined

Comment: My bad - didn't look close enough - `.val()` is used for HTML controls (`input` / `select`) - to get the "value" of a `td` - you need to use `.text()`

Comment: Yes freedomn-m. Thanks a lot. Here is the solution of my problem : var itemName = $(this).closest('tr').find('.col-name').text();

Answer (score 0):

```
var itemName = $(this).closest('tbody').find('.col-name').text();
```

try this,

is not an input elelment so I dont think you'll get anything with val()
instead I've used text(), or you can try other functions jquery provides, like html()

And out of all selectors you've tried to target `<td class="col-name">` , above seems to work fine, second one wont work, I didnt try every one of them.

Comment: this one didn't work because it returns : item 0 and item 1, but this one have worked for me :) :  var itemName = $(this).closest('tr').find('.col-name').text();

Comment: Yes, using 'tr' should narrow the search

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. After searching an answer to my question here is the solution of my problem :

```js
$("#productTableServerSide").on('change', '.server-dropdown', function (event) {
            //ancienne valeur
            var oldValue = $.data(this, 'itemValue'); 
            //nouvelle valeur
            var newValue = $(this).val();

            console.log('break1');
            
            //working 
            var itemName = $(this).closest('tr').find('.col-name').text();
            console.log('itemName : ', itemName);
            alert(itemName);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <p>My Example</p>
    <table id="productTableServerSide" class="table table-bordered" style="width:100%;">
        <thead class="thead-dark text-white">
            <tr>
                <th>Check</th>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>The product name</th>
                <th>The product value</th>
                <th>Dropdown</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
         <tr role="row" class="odd">
        <td class="col-checkbox sorting_1">
            <input id="check0" type="checkbox" class="server-checkbox">
        </td>
        <td class=" col-action">
            <a href="/Data/Product/0">Action</a>
        </td>
        <td class=" col-name">item   0</td>
        <td class=" col-value">3</td>
        <td class=" col-dropdown">
            <select id="drop3" class="server-dropdown custom-select custom-select-sm form-control form-control-sm" name="values">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3" selected="">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="2130554612">2130554612</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
        <td class="col-checkbox sorting_1">
            <input id="check1" type="checkbox" class="server-checkbox"> 
        </td>
        <td class=" col-action">
             <a href="/Data/Product/1">Action</a>
        </td>
        <td class=" col-name">item   1</td>
        <td class=" col-value">1436184776</td>
        <td class=" col-dropdown">
            <select id="drop1436184776" class="server-dropdown custom-select custom-select-sm form-control form-control-sm" name="values"> 
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="1436184776" selected="">1436184776</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I pulish it for the others, in case they have the same issue.

Have a nice day!